# How to identify which input need to pass for kettle Jobs when running in PDI tool?

Tags: transformation, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

We have many .ktr kettle jobs. we are new to these and We have found a way to run those in PDI tool. But we are unable to identify which input file need to pass for these kettle jobs when executing those in PDI(`Pentaho Data Integration`) tool.

Can anyone please explain how to understand or where to check that which input file need to pass for these kettle jobs during execution?

Comment: Its depend on which input file has used in your each job/transformation. Your question is very confused. You need to open each job/transformation and need to look if they use any input file or not.

Comment: they are using xml file as input file but where to check that which data need to pass inside that xml file as we cannot find this in kettle job. can you help how to analyze this by looking .ktr job script. @ Sakil Ahmmed

Comment: I believe it will not possible to give you a good answer without looking your kettle job file myself.

Comment: Can you generally tell where you can pass input file info in kettle job file as you know we are not authorized to add kettle job file here so. @Sakil Ahmmed